# Me deja un margen por debajo de la imagen en HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo un proyecto personal, y no entiendo por qué me agrega un pequeño margen debajo de la imagen:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Card Interactive</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/1RB9mqx/bg-main-desktop.png" alt="">
</body>

</html>
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para eliminar el margen de debajo de la imagen?

Foto de cómo queda el problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir una foto de como se ve el problema?

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta con la imagen @CuadCode

Comment: +1 por agregar correctamente un [repro].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema viene por el vertical-align asignado por defecto a muchos elementos.

Tienes varias soluciones
(usa la que mejor te funcione en tu styles.css):

```
img {vertical-align:middle}
```

o bien

```
img {display:block}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema esque la imagen no tiene la suficiente altura, tendrias que aumentar la anchura para que la altura se adapte proporcialmente y si no te importa estirar un poquito la imagen puedes probar esto:

```
* {
     position: fixed;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;

}

img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Espero que te ayude, si es asi, puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta :D